# Machine learning model training with hardware constraints

Tags: machine-learning

Just wondering if there is any approach for training a machine learning model on large training data where the hardware can't support the entire training data.

Comment: This question is *way too broad* for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question that depends on what kind of data you're looking at. The first place I would look is at a model that can treat the data iteratively, which wouldn't need the whole training set in memory. The best thing to do would be to try something like that and ask a question when you run into an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the crucial reasons for existance of **incremental learning** as well as techniques such as **stochastic gradient descent** (and its mini-batch generalizations); In general the only thing that has to fit into your hardware (such as GPU) is model itself, with enough capacity to parse a small batch of your training data. In particular all modern neural nets are trained in such manner (where data is sent through the model in batches, you do not have to ever put entire dataset into the memory).